# Using Await While Looping a Map Object

Tags: javascript, loops, dictionary, async.js

How can you iterate over each value in a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), in manner where [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) will be honored in the body of that loop?

Comment: a for loop over the .values() would be the way - if you want to access both key and values, iterate over .entries() instead

Comment: @Bravo Thank you. I used `.values()` in a [for await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) loop. This solved my problem.

Comment: gather the promises return from map fn, and then use Promise.all() to catch when all the promises return/ completes. 
https://www.techiediaries.com/promise-all-map-async-await-example/

Comment: @jatinderbhola - that will make all async code run in parallel - using a for loop will make it run in series - the question implies the latter is required

Comment: @LonnieBest you should answer your own question. It was just what I needed.

Comment: @drewish Ok, I went ahead an posted an answer. I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ultimately used [map.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) within a [for await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) loop.

Here's a contrived example that showcases [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) working within a loop:

```js
async function delay(ms)
{
  console.log(`Waiting ${ms} milliseconds . . .`);
  return new Promise((resolve)=>{ setTimeout(resolve, ms); });
}

async function main()
{
  let map = new Map([[1,"A"],[2,"B"],[3,"C"]]);

  for await (const value of map.values())
  {
          await delay(2000);
          console.log(value);
  }
}
main();
```